# Controling and monitorying number of simultaneous map/reduce tasks in YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have an Hadoop 2.2 cluster deployed on a small number of powerful machines. I have a constraint to use YARN as the framework, which I am not very familiar with.

1. How do I control the number of actual map and reduce tasks that will run in parallel? Each machine has many CPU cores (12-32) and enough RAM. I want to utilize them maximally.
2. How can I monitor that my settings actually led to a better utilization of the machine? Where can I check how many cores (threads, processes) were used during a given job?

Thanks in advance for helping me melt these machines :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.
In MR1, the mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum properties dictated how many map and reduce slots each TaskTracker had.

These properties no longer exist in YARN. Instead, YARN uses yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores, which control the amount of memory and CPU on each node, both available to both maps and reduces

Essentially:
YARN has no TaskTrackers, but just generic NodeManagers. Hence, there's no more Map slots and Reduce slots separation. Everything depends on the amount of memory in use/demanded

2.

Using the web UI you can get lot of monitoring/admin kind of info:

NameNode - http://:50070/ 
Resource Manager - http://:8088/

In addition Apache Ambari is meant for this:
http://ambari.apache.org/

And Hue for interfacing with the Hadoop/YARN cluster in many ways:
http://gethue.com/

Answer (score 3):

1. There is a [good guide](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html) on YARN configuration from Hortonworks
2. You may analyze your job in [Job History](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html) server. It usually may be found on port 19888. [Ambari](https://ambari.apache.org/) and [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) are also very good for cluster utilization measurement.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem, 
in order to increase the number of mappers, it's recommended to reduce the size of the input split (each input split is processed by a mapper and so a container). I don't know how to do it,

indeed, hadoop 2.2 /yarn does not take into account  none of the following settings

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize</name>
    <value>16777216</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.min.split.size</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.max.split.size</name>
    <value>16777216</value>
</property>
```

best